# Looping same feature file with different parameter in Karate

Tags: javascript, karate

I have a feature file with multiple scenarios.

1. I have test data in JSON file, need to execute the same feature file
   with different parameter rendered from JSON.
2. Also the above execution has to execute in parallel.

Share your view and thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes this is supported by Karate. Please read this part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features
2. Karate only supports parallelization at a feature-file level. So not supported currently (may be in the future). This is not an issue for most teams because you always have multiple feature files and your entire test suite will run as fast as possible.

Comment: Peter thanks for your response. Regarding my second question, we are having the use-case for testing the concurrency of our micro services. So we need to test the same feature file with multiple customer in parallel. Any suggestion for me here??

Comment: @Selva Karate is not (yet) a perf-testing tool. Either use JMeter or Gatling - or you might be able to use the Karate Java API (refer docs) to create threads yourself and call a feature file multiple times.

Comment: And now there's Karate-Gatling. I've started using it recently and I'm really liking it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling

Comment: please add example in code, as links are not ideal in stackoverflow rules

Comment: hi I posted a question here, thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78050655/karate-test-with-different-parameters-using-replace